# Update NSView frame every millisecond

Tags: macos, cocoa, graphics, frame, nsview

I'm trying to update an NSView's frame at every millisecond. It work for some frame but it blocks very quickly.

How should I do to make smooth updates ?

Comment: Does it work if you only update it every 60th of a second?

Comment: Why exactly do you need to update every millisecond?

Comment: DrewMcGowen It's a bit more complicated. I'm using Leap Motion and would like to update my frame at every finger position changes. I'm listening to these changes with a delegate method which is called about every millisecond.

0x7fffffff Same problem with this frame rate

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The WindowServer will only ever update the screen at a maximum of 60FPS (Unless you turn that off with Quartz Debug, but in general, it will be limited to 60FPS, and it will *never* be 1000FPS). Attempting to force redraw any more frequently than that is a waste of effort. I would expect, under normal circumstances, that calling `-setFrame:` on an NSView will cause `-setNeedsDisplay:` to be called, which means that your view will be redrawn the next time the WindowServer draws a frame, so even if you're calling `-setFrame:` 1000 times a second, it's not going to be drawing your view 1000 times per second. If you're seeing stuttering, I would bet that what's actually happening is that your view is taking more than 1/60th of a second to redraw. It's hard to do any non-trivial raster drawing (i.e. the kind you would be doing in `-[NSView drawRect:]`) in <1/60th of a second.

If you're trying to simply move the view (and you don't need to redraw it) you might try calling `-setFrameOrigin` and using Layer-backed views.  I would expect AppKit/CoreAnimation to be able to **re-position** a layer-backed view (without re-rasterizing it) in <1/60th of a second (with ease).

If you want something more complex that simply re-positioning a view, and you want it to happen at the max frame rate (again, 60FPS) you are likely going to want to look into using OpenGL.

But really, the take home message here is "don't try to do stuff 1000 times per second." When the Leap Motion delegate method is called, update your view's position, and let the WindowServer do the rest at its own pace.